# zsh read -q broken on OSX?

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm running `% read -q`, and then typing a single character which isn't `y`, `Y` or `n`. However, the value set in `$REPLY` isn't `n`, it is the character I typed.

The [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) for `read -q` explicitly says:

> Read only one character from the terminal and set name to ‘y’ if this
>   character was ‘y’ or ‘Y’ and to ‘n’ otherwise.

This behavior reproduces on OSX 10.7 using zsh 4.3.11 (default) and 5.0.0 (Homebrew), but not on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04, zsh 4.3.10) - on Linux, the value in `$READ` is `n`, as expected.

Also, I've tried running under `zsh -f`, same results (i.e., I don't think it's in my init scripts).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, and has been for two and a half years.  It was inadvertently lost by the patch in zsh-workers article 27188.  Patch in article 30949.